# Для чего нужен static_cast, как он работает и где его применяют?

Tags: c++

Для чего нужен static_cast, как он работает и где его применяют?

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B0#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.B2.D0.B5.D0.B4.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F_.D1.82.D0.B8.D0.BF.D0.BE.D0.B2_.D0.B2_.D1.8F.D0.B7.D1.8B.D0.BA.D0.B5_C.2B.2B

Answer (score 30, accepted):

У `static_cast` очень много различных применений. Его идея состоит в следующем: это ограниченный по мощи C-style cast. Ограничение нужно потому, что C-style cast может привести что угодно к чему угодно (ну, почти), и тем самым может скрыть ошибку. Например, вы можете случайно закастить `const char*` в `char*`, получив крэш в некоторых системах с аппаратной поддержкой const-памяти. `static_cast` вам такого не позволит.

Большую часть времени, когда вы хотите сделать явное преобразование типов (а я надеюсь, это бывает достаточно редко), вы хотите именно `static_cast`.

Формальный список всего, что умеет `static_cast`, [очень большой](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), я приведу лишь наиболее важные вещи, которые он умеет (а также которые он *не умеет*):

Что можно:

1. Преобразование указателя на родительский класс к указателю на дочерний класс. Объект по указателю **обязан** быть правильного дочернего класса, иначе undefined behaviour. Если вы не уверены и хотите проверить, тот ли подкласс у объекта, пользуйтесь `dynamic_cast` (он специально для этого предназначен).
2. Преобразования между числовыми типами. `int`, `long`, `char`, `unsigned int` — все их можно кастить друг в друга при помощи `static_cast`.
3. Можно закастить любое выражение в `void`. Результат будет вычислен и отброшен (но побочные эффекты, разумеется, выполнятся).
4. `static_cast` может привести константу `nullptr` к любому типу-указателю. Обычно это не нужно и можно полагаться на неявное преобразование типов, но иногда (например, для выбора нужной перегрузки функции) такое может пригодится.

Что нельзя:

1. Преобразование между указателями на в принципе несовместимые типы. Например, указатель на `double` нельзя привести к указателю на `int`. Для трюков с нарушением type safety пользуйтесь `reinterpret_cast`.
2. Указатели на типы, а также сами типы с несовместимыми атрибутами `const` и/или `volatile`. Если вам необходимо нарушить const-корректность, пользуйтесь `const_cast`.
3. Разумеется, вы не сможете привести указатель на функцию-член к указателю на обычную функцию, или указатель на код к указателю на данные. Для подобных грязных хаков пользуйтесь `reinterpret_cast`.

Ещё одной причиной использования `static_cast` (как и других C++-специфических преобразований типов) является лёгкость его поиска в исходниках, как глазами, так и поисковыми утилитами. Сишный каст (особенно его функциональную разновидность) очень легко пропустить в коде.

---

Для сравнения, «привычное» преобразование типов (C-style cast) [равносильно](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast) следующей последовательности:

1. `const_cast`.
2. Если `const_cast` не может дать нужный результат, то `static_cast` (но с разрешённым преобразованием к недообъявленному типу)
3. Если и так не выходит, то компилятор пробует в хвост к `static_cast` добавить `const_cast`.
4. Если и это не получается, то `reinterpret_cast`.
5. ... а если не выйдет, то к нему дописывается `const_cast`.

Comment: @VladD большое спасибо вам, пожалуй, я к этому ответу неоднократно обращусь. Очень на небольшую понятную статью похоже.

Comment: @perfect: Пожалуйста!