# Что такое static_cast?

Tags: c++

После С# стал изучать С++. Наткнулся на static_cast. Но не понимаю, что это такое. Это функция, метод, класс? Если да, то в каком пространстве имен она находится?

Comment: Операция делает явное допустимое приведение типа данных.

Comment: Это встроенное в язык ключевое слово.  Выглядит как шаблонная функция, но не совсем.   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/387985/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-static-cast-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%BD-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8-%D0%B3%D0%B4%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%8E%D1%82

Comment: Cppreference считает его оператором.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat слово operator на Cppreference  - не нашел. А вот про ключевое слово: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/keyword/static_cast

Comment: @Chorkov Одно другому не мешает, это и ключевое слово тоже. Он есть в списке операторов тут: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence